# Angular Bootstrap Modal popup autofocus not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented a [bootstrap modal using angular bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal) which works fine.

Here is a [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/XkZ4rDsssLXB7UuhP6GW?p=preview) for the code I have used.

In my modal I have only one input field (textbox) which needs to be filled by the user and a save and cancel button. I want that when the modal is shown the textbox should have the focus.

I tried the `autofocus` attribute which works otherwise not working in this case.

Pasted below is my html on the modal.

```
<div class="modal-header panel panel-heading">
    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="ok()">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Project</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" class="form-control" id="ProjectName" placeholder="Enter project name here" data-ng-model="ProjectName" tab-index="1"/>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" tab-index="2">Create</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()" tab-index="3">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

How do I get this to work ?

Comment: Hello @yasser cant you see focus in my link? I think i have provided working demo that what you need. please comment your views. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a [plunker link with the fix](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcEQXmxgUPosF0ZnYPIu?p=preview): you need to create a directive for it

```
app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
      scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
        console.log('value=',value);
        if(value === true) { 
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].focus(); 
          });
        }
      });
      element.bind('blur', function() {
        console.log('blur')
        scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
      })
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
<input ng-init="$element.focus()">
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

autofocus works

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>
```

Comment: It works only first time, doesn't work if I close the popup and reopen it again

Comment: Make sure your using the correct ui-bootstrap version. I just checked my site and it correctly sets the focus on the input on desktop or mobile even if I close and reopen the modal.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: The version i am using is 0.13.4.

Comment: I think you wrote your answer only for a input type text, as I can see on clicking Run Code snippet, question actually asks to autofocus in a bootstrap modal popup

Comment: Here is a working example of what you need http://plnkr.co/edit/Vb2jgo2CWhxKACd1qwND?p=preview

Comment: just put autofocus on the element you want to focus e.g. <button autofocus class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>

Comment: Works on textarea as well, every time I open a uibmodal

Answer (score 1):

This has now been [fixed](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1696) in version [0.13.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/releases/tag/0.13.0), see the bug report here: [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1696)